Why the test function space is countable union of $\mathcal{D}_{K_i}$
In the Rudin's functional analysis, in remark 6.9, It says there is countable collection of sets $K_i \subset \Omega$ such that $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)=\cup \mathcal{D}_{K_i}$
$\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$is the union of all $\mathcal{D}_K$ as $K$ range over all compact subset of $\Omega$
Why $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ can be the countable union of $\mathcal{D}_{K_i}$

You need to be a bit more specific as to how $\Omega$ is defined. If it is a reasonable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then we can pick $$ K_i = { x\in \Omega \ : \ \vert x \vert \leq i, \mathrm{dist}(x, \partial(\Omega \cap B_i(0)))\geq 1/i }. $$

This is because if $\Omega$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, there exists a sequence $(K_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of compact subsets of $\Omega$ such that $K_{i}$ is contained in the interior with respect to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of $K_{i+1}$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}K_{i} = \Omega$. Furthermore, if $K$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$, there exists some $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K \subseteq K_{i}$. Note that all of this is mentioned right under the definition of $\mathscr{D}(K)$ in the book.
One such example of a sequence is to define $K_{j}$ for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$ by
$$K_{j} := \{x\in\Omega : \|x\| \leq j \; \text{and} \; \text{dist}(x, \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \Omega ) \geq 1/j \}.$$
It can be verified that the sequence $(K_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ has all of the desired properties.
